# Crashes when opening activity through alias on manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an app that is a specialized web browser. A lot of users have asked for it to be listed as a browser on Android however I think that is pretty intrusive since it isn't a general purpose browser. So instead what I did is I created a component using an `activity-alias` and made it disabled by default and then the users can choose whether to enable it. This is what my alias looks like:

```
<activity-alias
            android:name="MyComponentName"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".MyMainActivity">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

Anyways, I've tested it on several Android versions and it works fine but I've gotten a few crashes over Crashlytics that look like this:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.MyMainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{mypackage/MyComponentName}
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{mypackage/MyComponentName}
       at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:152)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:60)
       at mypackage.MyMainActivity.onCreate(MyMainActivity.java:330)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{mypackage/MyComponentName}
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:314)
       at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:301)
       at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:281)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:152)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:60)
       at mypackage.MyMainActivity.onCreate(MyMainActivity.java:330)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? the line it is crashing on in my code is `super.onCreate()` on the `MyMainActivity`.

Thanks.

EDIT: Manifest section for MyMainActivity
Second edit: changed the `android:name="MyMainActivity"` to have a `.` before `MyMainActivity` but it didn't solve the issue.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyMainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
           >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

.... a bunch of other filters

</activity>
```

Comment: Can you include the manifest entry for `MyMainActivity`?

Comment: Editted the post with that in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue. There was a possibility given certain conditions that the `onCreate` of my `Application` class would disable the component before the `onCreate` on the `Activity` got a chance to start even when started using that component alias.

Answer (score 2):

Your manifest doesn't define the full package name for the activity. The [manifest documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm) states that the name attribute should be either the full class name, or preceded with a period (which substitutes the app's package name).

You can fix your crash by changing the manifest declaration to one of the formats below:

```
android:name=".MyMainActivity"
android:name="com.example.myapp.mypackage.MyMainActivity"
```

Comment: Good catch, that is on my main activity declaration actually, wonder why it only crashes on the alias. I'll make the change and deploy to beta users and come back and mark it as correct if the issue is gone. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you launch the activity explicitly via an intent from within the app? The documentation for the enabled attribute seems to state that the system can't instantiate the activity if its value is false - perhaps setting it to true will stop the crash?

Comment: I set the value to true if the user enables it. If it isn't enabled then it shouldn't show up on the dialog to choose an app when clicking on a link. I've tested this on several phones and several Android versions and it seems to work fine, I've even tested it on the phone models/versions that I'm getting crash reports for.

Comment: I'm assigning the points to this answer because I haven't had any more crash reports like this since I made the fix.

Comment: Well crap, just a couple of hours after thinking it was fixed I got my first crash report. It does seem to have slowed down the crash reports somehow because I was getting them very frequently and now this is the first one in two days.

Answer (score 0):

I think that application is not finding path of activity alias that you have created. Try to put .MyComponentName in name attribute in activity-alias.

Comment: My component name is actually "mypackage.mycomponentname" but I didn't think that mattered?